# In mongodb aggregate method order not maintained

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection as such:

```
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
 score: 2
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8b11c5de25042a06fe"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
 score: 4
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a0hehb"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAD,
 score: 3
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAD,
 score: 2
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a0j3bb"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAE,
 score: 5
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAE,
 score: 4
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de250wer46fs"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAF,
 score: 2
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de250423e6fg"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAF,
 score: 2
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
 score: 2
}
 {_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
 score: 2
}
{_id:ObjectId("5aa59c8411c5de25042a06fd"),
 id: Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC,
 score: 2
}
```

I am using this query so that i can fetch the results in the order i want to,i.e the order passed in the argument. Here data.enemy_id[1] = Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAD, data.enemy_id[2]= Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC, data.id =Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAE

```
   var order =[data.enemy_id[1],data.enemy_id[0],data.id];
        db.collection('Scores').aggregate([
        {$match: {id:{$in:order}}},
        {$addFields: {"__order": {$indexOfArray: [order, "$id" ]}}},
        {$sort: {"__order": 1}},
        {$group: {_id:'$id',score:{$max:'$score'}}},
        {$project: {_id:0,score:1}}
    ]).toArray().then((docs)=>{
        var score1 = JSON.stringify(docs,undefined,2);
        var score1 = JSON.parse(score1);
        console.log(score1);
```

I want to fetch the results in this way:;i.e. the highest score of id 'Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAD' , 'Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAC','Y19rvB489or4mvtxAAAE' in this order. But i am unabvle to fetch it in the desired ordered way
        [{score:3},{score:4},{score:5}]

Comment: Add a `"$first": "$__order"` within the `$group` and apply the `$sort` **after** the `$group` with the field still there. I presume the `id` values are what are in the array anyway so all matches will have the same index. Keep it using `$first`.

Comment: @NeilLunn  you are telling me this: {$group: {"$first": "$__order",_id:'$id',score:{$max:'$score'}}}, ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) is in the wrong place. It only becomes important to your ordering **after** the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/):

```
 var order =[data.enemy_id[1],data.enemy_id[0],data.id];
        db.collection('Scores').aggregate([
        {$match: {id:{$in:order}}},
        {$addFields: {"__order": {$indexOfArray: [order, "$id" ]}}},
        // {$sort: {"__order": 1}},    // <-- remove this one
        // Keep the __order field in the next stage
        {$group: {_id:'$id',score:{$max:'$score'}, "__order": { "$first": "$__order" } }},
        {$sort: {"__order": 1}},       // <-- move to here to actually sort
        {$project: {_id:0,score:1}}
    ]).toArray().then((docs)=>{
      ...
```

The [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage will **always** change the order of documents on output, which is why any [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) needs to be applied there if you expect a certain order in response.